# Is there a way to compile Node.js code to regular JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, compilation

Is there a way to compile Node.js code to regular JavaScript?
I've wanted to use Node.js code for my web application for a while.
I've tried to use Express, but there was no way I could make it work without converting the HTML file to EJS.
I know it is possible because of the way Create React App builds, but I don't know how to achieve that.

Any solution would help, and it would also help me if you could answer some of these questions
(these are some that I tried and gave up on):

- Is there a way to access the document variable with express (keep in mind that I'm working with a framework that requires to have access to the document variable)?
- Is there any way I could just import modules to my JavaScript file (basically using require() without node)?
- Is there any way I could ship the part of Node.js that I actually need togeher with my application (and yes, it is in fact the require() function)?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up a lot of concepts and I would strongly suggest reading more about JavaScript and the difference between executing it on the frontend (web browsers) and the backend (NodeJS)...

Here are a few (quick) answers to some of your questions:

1. Code that runs in NodeJS is regular JavaScript. However if you use NodeJS APIs, it will not run in a web browser, which has a different execution environment runtime.
2. The `document` object only exists in a web browser environment, it has no meaning in a NodeJS environment which is a backend.
3. `require` is a NodeJS API to load CommonJS packages, it does not exist in a web browser environment. There are alternatives like RequireJS or Browserify, or you can use import for ES modules (with proper CORS details set up).
4. Express is a server-side routing library, it is not meant to run in web browser environment.

If you are trying to build a web application, you could start by looking into JS frameworks that do the heavy lifting for you like Svelte, Angular, React, Vue (to name only the most popular ones).